# How to handle token(coming from external service) expiration in core

Tags: c#, .net-core

There is an API, lets call it API_ServiceProvider which can only be invoked using token. And the token is being generated by another API lets call it API_TokenGenerator. Now to invoke API_ServiceProvider to get data I need token from API_TokenGenerator. But this token expires in 10 min. Once I have the token in for 10 min I keep calling API_ServiceProvider. But when it expires my calls to API_A will fail and I need to get new token now. How can this best handled this in .Net core?

Comment: Can’t you just store the time the token will expire next to the token and fetch a new one if you realise the next call might exceed that time?

Comment: Well the assumption from API_B owner is that I should not have logic based on time(it can change). I should build my logic to accept HttpStatus code 403 and raise a new request if 403 happens.

Comment: It should really be a 401, as 403 means Forbidden, not Unauthorized.  Under the current mainstream web model (OAuth2) you will have access to the expiry time, so it's not a big ask for API_B to supply it.  If it's not an option you will can build retry logic into a custom `HttpClientHandler` that you supply when constructing your `HttpClient`, which would catch the 401 (in `SendAsync()`), get a new token, and try again.  That way it would be seamless wherever you use your `HttpClient`.  It's an extra call that would be unnecessary if you could preempt it, though.

Comment: Thanks for replying @sellotape. but I am just going to use the token to invoke API_ServiceProvider and ideally token validation logic should be API_ServiceProvider end and not mine. After getting token from API_TokenGenerator all I have to do is invoke API_ServiceProvider with this token. I can do by putting retry logic while making API_ServiceProvider call and when I get error I should get new token. But I need to know if there is better way of implementing same in .Net core

Comment: Also I renamed the API's for better understanding. API_A is now API_ServiceProvider and API_B is API_TokenGenerator

Comment: I not aware of Core providing any better solutions for this when using custom authentication (over, say, Framework).